# Python - OpenCV - Calibrating Camera and Rectangle's Border Detection

Tags: python, opencv, camera, webcam, camera-calibration

I am having problems detecting a rectangle's border after the camera calibration using the OpenCV [official](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html]) documentation with a chessboard. This is the following code I am using:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    _, img = cap.read()

    if img is not None:

        # load data for undistortion
        with np.load('R1.npz') as X:
            mtx, dist, _, _ = [X[i] for i in ('mtx', 'dist', 'rvecs', 'tvecs')]

        h, w = img.shape[:2]
        newcameramtx, roi = cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx, dist, (w, h), 1, (w, h))

        # undistort
        dst = cv2.undistort(img, mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx)

        # crop the image
        x, y, w, h = roi
        dst = dst[y:y + h, x:x + w]

        # convert to gray scale
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(dst, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        # gaussian blur to remove noise
        gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
        # threshold
        thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, 1, 1, 11, 2)
        # find contours in the thresholded image
        _, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        # get image area
        image_area = gray.size

        for i in contours:
            # if area of box > half of image area, it is possibly the biggest blob
            if cv2.contourArea(i) > image_area / 2:
                perimeter = cv2.arcLength(i, True)
                # approximate the contours
                approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(i, 0.02 * perimeter, True)
                # draw the contours
                cv2.drawContours(dst, [approx], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

This how I store camera matrix and distortion coefficient:

```
# termination criteria
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

# prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((6*7,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:7,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)

# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.
# omitted code
for fname in images:
    # omitted code
    # Find the chess board corners
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (7,6),None)

    # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
    if ret == True:
        objpoints.append(objp)

        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners2)

        # global mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs
        # calibrate webcam and save output

        ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)
        np.savez("R1", ret=ret, mtx=mtx, dist=dist, rvecs=rvecs, tvecs=tvecs)
```

After the camera calibration, the system does not detect grid's borders when the grid is moved after 1000 px horizontally in the x-direction (from x = 1000 px to x = 1240 px).

This is very weird because the output of the calibrated camera is not curved, and the program should not have problems detecting the rectangle's borders.

Before the camera calibration (with curve output) it used to detect perfectly the rectangle's border. I am really confused because should be the other way around.

To calibrate the camera I've used around 90 images, trying to be more precise, from all the angulations possible. At this point, I don't know if a doing something wrong when I retrieve the camera matrix, distortion coefficients, rotation and translation vectors using `np.load` as shown in the code fragment above.

These are the parameters of the `undistort` function:

```
Mtx:  [[  1.44771567e+03   0.00000000e+00   5.47978617e+02]
 [  0.00000000e+00   1.45032420e+03   3.76928336e+02]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00]]
Dist:  [[-0.10714946  0.00687251  0.00295331 -0.00231975 -0.18869188]]
New Camera Matrix: [[  1.38938562e+03   0.00000000e+00   5.38801146e+02]
 [  0.00000000e+00   1.38108777e+03   3.79614791e+02]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00]]
```

Can anyone give me a hand? I really don't know what I am doing wrong.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You don't show how you save the "R1.npz", so it's somewhat hard to tell you whether you load it correctly. However there's nothing simpler than writing a short script to verify that, give it a shot. Furthermore, without providing us the undistort parameters as well as some sample image to test it with, it's a bit hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: Hi @DanMašek thanks for your reply. How can I test it than? It would be helpful if I add the fragment of code where I save the .npz file?

Comment: You can verify the correctness of your loading algorithm in the script that saves the file -- you already have the original values, so just load the file back into a different set of variables and compare them for equality with the original. | Yes, please attach all relevant code, ideally also the undistrort parameters from your calibration and sample image (just save one frame from the camera in the beginning of your loop).

Comment: @DanMašek I've just edited the code, thank you for your help!

Comment: @DanMašek I could not find a solution in these days. What do you think about the code used to create the .npz file and the undistort parameters?